# Getting Sum from a randint loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, sum

I would like to get the sum of the random numbers produced by my loop
This is my loop

```
for i in range(1, rolls + 1):
    random1 = str([random.randint(1, 6)])
    print(f'Roll {i}:' + random1)
```

```
The output looks like this 
Roll 1:[2]
Roll 2:[5]
Roll 3:[1]
Roll 4:[1]
Roll 5:[2]
Roll 6:[4]
Roll 7:[2]
Roll 8:[5]
Roll 9:[1]
Roll 10:[6]
```

How do i get the sum from the [brackets]?

Answer (score 4):

Using a variable to keep track of the sum:

```
total = 0
for i in range(1, rolls + 1):
    n = random.randint(1, 6)
    total += n
    print(f'Roll {i}: [{n}]')

print(f"Total: {total}")
```

Using `sum`:

```
nums = [random.randint(1, 6) for i in range(1, rolls + 1)]

for i, n in enumerate(nums):
     print(f'Roll {i}: [{n}]')

print(f"Total: {sum(nums)}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, here's a slightly shorter approach using the `:=` operator in 3.8+:

```py
total = 0

for i in range(1, rolls + 1):
    total += (n := random.randint(1, 6))
    print(f'Roll {i}: [{n}]')

print(f"Total: {total}")
```

Comment: I figured this was a little advanced for someone asking this question so I didn't include it. but still like the alternative. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
sum = 0
for i in range(1, rolls + 1):
    rand = random.randint(1, 6)
    sum += rand
    random1 = str(rand)
    print(f'Roll {i}:' + random1)
print(sum)
```

Comment: Don't suggest someone overwrite a python builtin! This is also just a copy of my answer btw

Comment: Try to avoid using the builtin `sum` for your variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a variable that adds up all the random numbers

```
sum_number = 0
for i in range(1, rolls + 1):
    random_number = random.randint(1, 6)
    random1 = str([random_number])
    print(f'Roll {i}:' + random1)
    sum_number += random_number
print(sum_number)
```

Or you could rewrite it

```
random_number_list = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(rolls)]
sum_number = sum(random_number_list)
# print random number
for i,random_number in enumerate(random_number_list):
    print(f'Roll {i+1}:' + random1)
print(sum_number)
```

If you don't need to see the print, you just need the first two lines of code

Comment: hmm, generally you wouldn't mix f-strings with string concatenation. I feel like you would either use one or the other.

Comment: Yes, I also recommend using one. I just copied his original print code